# How to disable anti-aliasing in SKLabelNode?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I want to use a pixel font in my SpriteKit game.
But I can't use a bitmap font because I need to support many languages (too many characters).
So I should use a ttf font file.

I tried the following code, but characters were blurred by anti-aliasing.

```
let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"My-Pixel-Font")
myLabel.text = "Hello"
myLabel.fontSize = 10
myLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 100.0)
myLabel.fontColor = SKColor.GrayColor()
self.addChild(myLabel);
```

Is there a good way to disable anti-aliasing in SKLabelNode?

My English is not good.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `[textureFromNode:]` method on your `SKView` to get your `SKLabelNode`'s texture, set it's `filteringMode` property to `SKTextureFilteringNearest` and create new `SKSpriteNode` with that texture.

Comment: Wouldn't the font render the anti-aliasing regardless of this?  The only thing you are changing is how the texture should render when scaling.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon You can render the label with small size to disable anti-aliasing and then scale it's texture to normal size.

Comment: I guess for a pixel font that is ok

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to solve the problem thanks to your answer.

Comment: There has got to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

```
let label = SKLabelNode()
label.text = "Test"
let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: view.texture(from: label))
node.texture?.filteringMode = .nearest
addChild(node)
```